# Web service client skipping JSON fields if key starts with underscore

Tags: java, json, jersey-client

I have written a java REST client using Jersey 2.17
The code looks like this:

```
    public <T> T query(Class<T> responseType, Result previous) {
         ...
      for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
        webTarget = webTarget.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      return webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
    }
```

Code is working as expected except one thing.
JSON object returned by the service contains a list of objects with such fields:

```
...
   "_type": "Package"
   "resourceId": "nimbusnodeweb-0.0.1_20141028083104790",
   "_oid": "544f5468e4b0b148bedbcfed",
...
```

When I am getting my object back from the query method, those _type and _oid properties are set to null. The problem is that they are object identifiers.
I can't figure out how to configure this WebTarget object to make it understand keys that start with underscore.
My target java object looks like this:

```
public class PackageInfo {
private String  _type;  // = "Package"
private String  resourceId;
private String  _oid;
...
```

I even put two setters for those fields

```
    /**
 * @param _oid the _oid to set
 */
public void setOid(String _oid) {
    this._oid = _oid;
}

/**
 * @param _oid the _oid to set
 */
public void set_oid(String _oid) {
    this._oid = _oid;
}
```

Nothing works.
Any clues will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Apparently, Jackson parser which is sitting underneath Jersey implementation is not up to par.
I used Google GSON and it worked wonderfully.
Here is the code:

```
//        return webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(responseType);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
        InputStream entity = (InputStream) response.getEntity();
        return gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(entity), responseType);
```